# Unable to see UI when launching cocoa based app in VSCode on macOS

Tags: clang++, vscode-debugger

I have been experimenting with building macos apps with vscode and clang++.  I have little experience of command line access to compilers, however, in a few hours I was able to build an app that includes both objective-c source (and the required frameworks) as well as c++.

The problem i have run into is that when vscode launches the debugger, it seems to force the app to run as command line only.  Windows created by the app (via objective-c Cocoa) will not display.  This is not a problem with the code, running the same app via finder without the debugger the UI displays fine.  Indeed, if I also wrap it in an .app bundle and double click it from finder, it runs exactly as desired without launching terminal at all.

Does anyone know how i can run it as an app from within vscode?  im hoping it some environment variable i need to set in the launch.json, or suchlike...

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem has gone away when i installed codelldb and changed the debugger to in the launch.json to "lldb"

I have no idea why, or what is going on under-the-hood here, but I hope that helps someone else.